# Why is Custom Middleware Still Being Run?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

**Platform**

.Net Core 2.2 Web App

**Scenario**

I wrote some custom middleware with the intent to be executed only when my request path matches a specified location. When it runs, it does a lookup from a database and checks a piece of data. Under certain circumstances, the middleware will redirect the user to a new url instead of letting them view the requested one.

**Problem**

The middleware seems to be cached or something. I don't understand it. When I request `localhost:6000/url-that-should-work`, I'm magically getting the wrong page at a different url. However when I use Fiddler, it's not a redirect. It's like that's the page that I actually requested. The weird part is that a) I have my middleware code commented out in `Startup.cs` and b) when I go into incognito mode, the behavior works as expected. Also, if I change the debug port to something different, it works as well. Also, when I put a breakpoint in my middleware, if I go to `/url-that-should-work`, the request path is the wrong url.

**Code**

Startup.cs

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseAuthentication();

//app.UseEndpointRouting();
//app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/move/booking"), appBuilder =>
//{
//    appBuilder.UseMoveBookingWorkflowPermission();
//});

app.UseMvc();
```

Middleware redirect line that should not be executing

```
context.Response.Redirect(context.Request.PathBase + previousPath + context.Request.QueryString, true);
```

Comment: The issue you're facing may be caused by browser caching. Why don't you try appending a header that would disable cache to the response?

Comment: @HirasawaYui I don't know how a browser caches code, but that's the behavior it looks like. Do you know where I would put that header at or what it would look like? I'm a little new to custom middleware.

Comment: Do you configure your middleware at the end of your startup?

Comment: @HirasawaYui Alright, as soon as I did a hard-reload on the browser, it worked as expected. Before I did that, when I would put a breakpoint in my middleware and see what the request path was, it was always the wrong url. I'm completely lost.

Comment: Try adding a dummy parameter so that the redirect url would look different each time. Like: context.Request.QueryString + "&randomGuid="+Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

Comment: @ShervinIvari Added my full Startup.cs code.

Comment: @ShervinIvari Before my middleware or after ```app.UseMvc()```

Comment: sorry add your middleware at the end.

Comment: Well, since I did a hard-reload before I did all of this, it's tough to make it not work again to see if this fixes it. Give me some time to confirm.

Comment: Try using the internet explorer 11 and refresh your page a few times. This browser is famous for stupidly caching every request possible.

Comment: add your middleware at the end after route or MVC configs.

Comment: @ShervinIvari Adding my ```.UseWhen...``` after ```app.UseMvc()``` has seemed to do the trick. I haven't had anymore issues since then.

Comment: @James it is because of middleware order,I mention more detail on my answer.Happy to help!

Comment: @ShervinIvari Well I feel dumb now. I wasn't running into an issue because when I moved the middleware to run after ```app.UseMvc()```, my middleware wasn't getting hit at all.

Comment: @ShervinIvari Should I be changing the way I'm redirecting the url in my middlware?

Comment: @James If the logic of your middleware is simple, it is ok but if you want to follow separation of concerns its better to create new middleware class.

Comment: @James It's ok, Even best developers sometimes do silly mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of those "I'm stupid" moments. The issue was that when I was redirecting the response, I was specifying that I wanted it to be permanent.

**Old**

```
context.Response.Redirect(context.Request.PathBase + previousPath + context.Request.QueryString, true);
```

**New**

```
context.Response.Redirect(context.Request.PathBase + previousPath + context.Request.QueryString, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to .Net Core documentation

> The order of your middlewares can change their **functionality**,
>   **security** and **performance**.

For example in this configuration at **Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseResponseCompression();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
}
```

Static files aren't compressed with this middleware order. The Razor Pages responses can be compressed. this simple example shows how the functionality will change.
Ordering matters in the Configure method, It can either make a response or pass the request to the next piece of middleware.

If still, you have a problem you can Rewrite URL Middleware.

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
.AddRewrite(//some options);
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Hope it it helps!